# POM for springboot app

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a springboot app and I'm having some trouble to make the pom for this app work.

I seem to get this error:

```
                Multiple annotations found at this line:
            - Failure to transfer org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will 
             not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:
             1.10.19 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to 
             transfer org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
             reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:
             1.10.19 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. at 
             org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238) at 
             org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206) at 
             org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585) at 
             org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503) at 
             org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421) at 
             org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246) at 
             org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367) at 
             org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205) at 
             org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215) at 
             org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188) at 
             org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119) at
```

Heres the code form my pom, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>ar.gob.snr.encuestaSNR</groupId>
        <artifactId>encuesta-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>EncuenstaSNR</name>
        <description>Encuesta de algo</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>Brixton.RC2</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>


        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.7</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshot-repository</id>
                <name>Maven2 Snapshot Repository</name>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-releases</id>
                <name>Spring Releases</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

    </project>
```

It's looks like I'm having trouble with some definitions but I'm not sure which ones.
I'm not used to working with the pom, since I'm a front end developer, but I really need to make this work to get my api back online :P and keep working on the front end. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had a network error or someone cancelled the operation whilst it was downloading the Mockito dependency. Maven has subsequently cached that failed attempt and wont reattempt until some update interval has passed.

You can force maven to try downloading it again using the `-U` flag, e.g.

`mvn clean install -U`